# in Handson table how can i get comma separated field in a column?

Tags: angularjs

In handsontable a column has data like this : 24999-99999
I want to convert like this comma separated: 24,999-99,999

how can i acheive this for entire column in angular js handson table ???

Handsontable full.min.js version : 0.28.4
Angular js version : 1.4

Comment: @charlietfl I think you should not mark it as Duplicate , it's not JS formating , the question is about Handson table library, and the issue with formatting in this library is not similar to JS one

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to write your own render.

```
function numberRenderer(hotInstance, TD, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  var valueArray = value.split('-');
  var str = parseInt(valueArray[0]).toLocaleString('en-IN') + '-' + parseInt(valueArray[1]).toLocaleString('en-IN');
  TD.innerHTML = str;
}


columns: [
  {
    data: 'yourcolumn',
    renderer: numberRenderer
  }
]
```